# Can not resolve symbol View in angular2/core

Tags: angular

I'm using **Angular 2.0.0-beta.17**. Previously I was working on **Angular 2.0.0-beta.9**

So following code was working previously

```
import { Component, View, OnInit,AfterViewInit, } from 'angular2/core';
```

But now it is giving following error.

> Can not resolve symbol View in angular2/core

So I was wondering is View is moved to another module?

Answer (score 2):

There is no `@View()` anymore. Just move the parameters to `@Component()`